# Adding elements from a List to a List of Lists

Tags: java, list, integer

I trying to write some code in Java - I have two Lists:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists;
List<Integer> listOfIntegers;
```

I want to add each of the `Integer`s in `listOfIntegers` to a new element (`List`) in `listOfLists`, then I need to clear `listOfIntegers`

I tried:

```
listOfLists.add(listOfIntegers);
listOfIntegers.clear();
```

but this clears the reference to the `List` in `listOfLists`

Thanks to Manuel Silva I came up with what I need:

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer i : lineIntegersList)
{
    newList.add(i);
}

listOfLists.add(newList);                   
lineIntegersList.clear();
```

Comment: Why you need a list of lists?

Comment: If code you posted just now was the one you ware looking for then you don't need to write your own `for` loop. Just use copping constructor like `List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(lineIntegersList);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOlists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
singleList.add("hello");
singleList.add("world");
listOlists.add(singleList);

ArrayList<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<String>();
anotherList.add("this is another list");
listOlists.add(anotherList);
```

thanks @tster - here you instantiate your "parent list" and as you would know how to do - just create a child list to add to the parent.. :D

Answer (score -1):

```
for (Integer i: listOfIntegers) {
 List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
 list.add(i);
 listOfLists.add(list);
}
```

This solution basically adds a new List with one element for each integer in the list of integer to the initial list of list